# JQuery function not removing class properly (select2Buttons)

Tags: jquery, css

I'm new at JQuery and I'm trying to change a html select with Jquery, so they should look like buttons. To achieve this, I'm using this plugin (working example): [select2Buttons](http://o-sam-o.github.io/select2Buttons/).

But I'm facing a problem. My select works only 2 times, because, as far as I know, my both select options are getting the selected applied:

```
<option value="" selected="selected">Code X</option>
```

Someone could help me with this? I'm using the same code as the example and in the example the could looks fine. I tried to Google it, but I didn't find anyone using this plugin.
I could use other plugins/solutions, but I need to keep the select.

Thanks in advance for your help!

EDIT: Here's my code so far https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LvVyOa?editors=0010

Comment: Mateus - please show us what you have tried so far (code sample/jsfiddle/etc.).

Comment: selected="selected" is XHTML syntax. In HTML5 you just type selected. Please post some code as your question is not very clear. What does "my select works only 2 times" mean? how many selects do you have in page?

Comment: Sorry, I was using the plugin example code, so I didn't put ir twice, but here's my code: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LvVyOa?editors=0010
I have 1 select with 2 options. "works 2 times" means that neither one of the options are loaded selected, but when I click in a option, the selected property is applied. When I click on the other option, both will have selected, and none "selected" are removed in any time.

Comment: I update my code to this: https://codesandbox.io/s/mzp183wkqy

Now I'm removing the "selected" property, but after running two times the code only return the first value. Can someone help me?